# Get File Name and Parent Folder of URL

Tags: javascript, substring

This javascript will get the whole path and the file name however the idea is to retrieve the file name + extension and its parent folder so it returns this:

*/thisfolder/thanks.html*

```
var url = "www.example.com/get/thisfolder/thanks.html";
var path = url.substring(url.indexOf('/')+1, url.lastIndexOf('.'));
alert(path)
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evanmoore/gwu7axzv/5/)

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with jQuery ;)

Comment: this is not jquery, this is pure js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `.split()`, you can select the last 2 elements and join them together after:

```js
var url = "www.example.com/get/thisfolder/thanks.html";
var path = url.split('/').slice(-2).join('/'); 
alert(path);
```

Comment: Thanks. this really helped solve the overall challenge I'm setting up. Thanks again.

Comment: For a cross-platform solution, use `Path.sep` (from Node.js) instead of `'/'`

Answer (score 1):

You could split by `/`:

```
var parts = url.split("/");
var filename = parts.pop();
var parent = parts.pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using array:

```
var paths = url.split("/");
var path = paths[paths.length - 2] + "/" + paths[paths.length - 1];
```